# React seeing all but on array

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a child component that sees all the props but one array that I am trying to map over.

react dev tool sees the array:

[image]

but I get "Cannot read property 'map' of undefined"

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const nav = this.props.data.nav.map(i => `<li><a href="#${i}">${i}</a></li>`)
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="left">
          <h1>{this.props.data.name}</h1>
          <p>{this.props.data.tag}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <h2>{this.props.data.t1}</h2>
          <h3>{this.props.data.t2}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="header-contact">
          <a rel="noopener" href="tel:+14156943568">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} /> {this.props.data.phone} 
          </a>
          <a rel="noopener" href="mailto:tim.smith.hdg@gmail.com">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="at" /> {this.props.data.email}
          </a>
        </div>
        <nav id="nav" className='nav'>
          <ul>
            {
              //nav
            }
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I'm using the `<Header />` component in the follow way:

```
class Resume extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { header: {}, skills: {} }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        ...data
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="resume">
        <Header data={this.state.header} />
        <Skills data={this.state.skills} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check that `props.data` is defined, and that `props.data.nav` is an array, to address the errors.

The reason you need to perform this check is because the `props.data.nav` is not present during the first `render()` of the `<Header />` component. This is because the `nav` data is only available after the `componentDidMount()` hook in `<Resume />` is called (which happens after the first render of `<Header />`)

You could make the following adjustment to resolve this:

```
class Header extends Component {

  // [UPDATE] add helper method to simplify safer access to data.nav array
  getNavItems() {

      // If no data, return empty array
      if(!this.props.data) return [];

      // If nav not an array, return empty array
      if(!Array.isArray(this.props.data.nav)) revturn [];

      // Safely access/return nav array
      return this.props.data.nav;
  }

  render() {

    // [UPDATE] use local helper getNavItems method to safely access item array
    const nav = this.getNavItems().map(i => `<li><a href="#${i}">${i}</a></li>`)
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="left">
          <h1>{this.props.data.name}</h1>
          <p>{this.props.data.tag}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <h2>{this.props.data.t1}</h2>
          <h3>{this.props.data.t2}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="header-contact">
          <a rel="noopener" href="tel:+14156943568">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} /> {this.props.data.phone} 
          </a>
          <a rel="noopener" href="mailto:tim.smith.hdg@gmail.com">
          <FontAwesomeIcon icon="at" /> {this.props.data.email}
          </a>
        </div>
        <nav id="nav" className='nav'>
          <ul>
            {
              //nav
            }
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: it is seen as an object

Comment: @Tithos correct, `data` is an object - did the above solution work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show from where `this.props.data.nav` comes from? Maybe when the component mounts, this.props.data or this.props.data.nav is undefined. React dev tool shows the array because after the error, this.props.data.nav is already set and not undefined. Try something like:

`var nav = null;
if(this.props.data != undefined && this.props.data.nav != undefined){
   nav = this.props.data.nav.map(i => "<li><a href="#${i}">${i}</a></li>")
}`

Comment: class Resume extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super();
    this.state = { header: {}, skills: {} }
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.setState({
        ...data
    });
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="resume">
        <Header data={this.state.header} />
        <Skills data={this.state.skills} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Comment: Have you tried the code I wrote above, any error or changes? Can you log the contents of `this.props` in render method of the Header component?

Answer (score 1):

You get map is undefined cause you don't get an array. You can't map undefined. The way I will do this will be to get an empty array if I don't have the props yet. This way you can still map over it but receive no element

```
class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const navData = this.props.data && this.props.data.nav || []
    const nav = navData.map(i => `<li><a href="#${i}">${i}</a></li>`)
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="left">
          <h1>{this.props.data.name}</h1>
          <p>{this.props.data.tag}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <h2>{this.props.data.t1}</h2>
          <h3>{this.props.data.t2}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="header-contact">
          <a rel="noopener" href="tel:+14156943568"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} /> {this.props.data.phone}</a>
          <a rel="noopener" href="mailto:tim.smith.hdg@gmail.com"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="at" /> {this.props.data.email}</a>
        </div>
        <nav id="nav" className='nav'>
          <ul>
            {
              //nav
            }
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Or you can handle this case from the parent also

```
class Parent extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Header data={this.state.header} nav={this.state.header && this.state.header.nav || []} /> 
      </div>
    )
  }
}


class Header extends Component {
  render() {
    const nav = this.props.nav.map(i => `<li><a href="#${i}">${i}</a></li>`)
    return (
      <div className="header">
        <div className="left">
          <h1>{this.props.data.name}</h1>
          <p>{this.props.data.tag}</p>
        </div>
        <div className="right">
          <h2>{this.props.data.t1}</h2>
          <h3>{this.props.data.t2}</h3>
        </div>
        <div className="header-contact">
          <a rel="noopener" href="tel:+14156943568"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faPhone} /> {this.props.data.phone}</a>
          <a rel="noopener" href="mailto:tim.smith.hdg@gmail.com"><FontAwesomeIcon icon="at" /> {this.props.data.email}</a>
        </div>
        <nav id="nav" className='nav'>
          <ul>
            {
              //nav
            }
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: I can't see any difference in your answer comparing to mine. Can you explain?

Comment: @PedroSimão o sorry, I didn't refresh my screen and I didn't see your answer. My bad sorry. Gonna upvote your :)